# How to share Mac System which has Lions OS 10.7?

Tags: macos

I was able to share my mac system screen using VNC server in Snow leopard OS but now I have upgraded the my Mac OS to Lion OS. Now VNC server is not compatible with Lion OS.
So can any one help me how to share my Mac system so that others can access my system remotely and run the iPhone application in XCode and able to see the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you checked out the built in Screen Sharing in OS X? Check out System Preferences -> Sharing -> Screen Sharing. Click on the Computer Settings button and you should see a dialog which allows you to enable VNC connections.

You should then be able to use any VNC Client like Chicken of the VNC to connect to the remote system running Lion.